# How to run a thread for a given time period and then return in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create a thread that listens for packets for a given time period (say 30 seconds) and then returns any messages that are received whilst listening. I can do the packet collection stuff, but what is the code pattern for the threading / blocking code that lets the asynch activity run for some set time period?

thanks

Comment: I'm somewhat skeptical that this is actually a duplicate, but this question isn't clear as to whether the primary thread blocks on the listening thread or expects an asynchronous response of some sort after 30 seconds. They're very different patterns, so anyone encountering this question with the latter requirement should probably ask a new, more specific question.

Comment: @Shog9, not the right place, but as I see you're around, and I can't quickly work it out from meta: will Markus be able to see my comment on his deleted answer, or is there no point bothering with such niceties?

Comment: He would have if I hadn't deleted the answer, @Benjol. I generally don't bother with comments on non-answers that are years old though.

Comment: @Shog9, woops, I missed that detail :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the code you are using to listen for packets, but basically (in pseudocode):

```
while(remainingTime > 0) {
   packet = listenForPackets(remainingTime);
   remainingTime = (initialTime + 30) - currentTime;
}
```

Comment: where does the threading logic go? waiting for a time period is trivial - as this example shows - what I dont know is what threading pattern/relationships I need...